# Why is the Python dict more efficient than set when it comes to finding/updating values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

When I was solving the leetcode 3sum problem, I submitted the following code:

```
class Solution1:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return []
        res = set()
        nums.sort()
        for firstEle in range(len(nums)-2):
            if firstEle > 0 and nums[firstEle] == nums[firstEle - 1]:
                continue
            target = 0 - nums[firstEle]
            dic = {}
            for j in range(firstEle+ 1,len(nums)):
                if target - nums[j] in dic:
                    res.add((nums[firstEle], target - nums[j], nums[j]))
                else:
                    dic[nums[j]] = j
        return list(map(list, res))
```

and got an runtime of ~844 ms.

I replaced `dict` with `set`, and modified the code as follows:

```
class Solution2:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        if len(nums) < 3:
            return []
        res = set()
        nums.sort()
        for firstEle in range(len(nums)-2):
            if firstEle > 0 and nums[firstEle] == nums[firstEle - 1]:
                continue
            target = 0 - nums[firstEle]
            mem = set()
            for j in range(firstEle+ 1,len(nums)):
                if target - nums[j] in mem:
                    res.add((nums[firstEle], target - nums[j], nums[j]))
                else:
                    mem.add(nums[j])
        return list(map(list, res))
```

then got a runtime of ~1044 ms.

Why did the data structure `set` downgrade the efficiency?

Updated:

I tested the code on my laptop:

```
import timeit
s1 = Solution1()
s2 = Solution2()

print("dict:", timeit.timeit(lambda: s1.threeSum([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]), number=100000))

print("set:", timeit.timeit(lambda: s2.threeSum([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4]), number=100000))
```

and got the output:

```
dict: 0.671448961016722
set: 0.7314219229156151
```

Environment:

*MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)*

*CPU: 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5*

*RAM: 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3*

*Python version: 3.6*

It seems `set` is still slower.

Comment: I would not call a single execution on a remote server which you have no control over (and is shared by probably several hundred users) a good sample size

Comment: `frozenset`, `set`, and `dict` are basically the same in performance (the differences are so minor is it practically irrelevant).  In your case you should test this on your own, off of a server.  Try it on your local machine and run your code 1000 times and average the time the function takes to get an accurate reading. Also `dicts` were slightly changed in python 3.7 so you may get different results between 3.7 and something like 3.6.

Comment: Repeated several times, `dict` still beats `set` for ~ 100 ms.

Comment: @jabberwoo on leetcode or on your machine?

Comment: Oops, on leetcode...I should do it locally :P

Comment: @jabberwoo as everyone has said you can't use a server as a reference for how fast a function runs.

Comment: OK, got it, my bad :P